# Retrieving member data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, concrete5, data-retrieval

I have a members page where people can download pdfs upon signup. The signup is recorded to a MySQL db. I use Concrete5 as my CMS.

Is it possible to retrieve which pdfs have been downloaded by which member after they have signed in?
I have access to PHP MyAdmin but don't know what to look for.

thanks

Comment: Added the concrete5 tag.

Comment: It's your database. You tell us!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `DownloadStatistics` table.
There you can find these fields:

- `dsID` is the record identifier
- `fID` is the ID of the downloaded file (references the `Files`.`fID` field)
- `fvID` is the ID of the file version (`fID` and `fvID` references the same fields of the `FileVersions` table)
- `uID` is the ID of the user that downloaded the file (references the `Users`.`uID` field)
- `rcID` is the ID of the page where the user downloaded the file from (references the `Pages`.`cID` field)
- `timestamp` contains the date/time when the download started